# why nslookup domain for self hosted app gives error ";; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.15, trying next server" but not other domains?

Tags: networking, dns, ubuntu-18.04, nslookup, coredns

I do not know why is this happening, I have a self hosted web app for which I use ddns that points to my router WAN ip, if I use 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 or anyoutside dns it works fine .
I also have my own coredns server running on ip 192.168.1.15 on port 53.
After ssh to this node, if I change the /etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver 192.168.1.15
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

then if I do `nslookup my-self-hosted.ddns.com` I get errror: but gets resovled to public wan.

```
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.15, trying next server
Server:     8.8.4.4
Address:    8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my-self-hosted.ddns.com
Address: 52.71.100.186
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.15, trying next server
```

The web app is also running on the same node 192.168.1.15 but It should not matter in my opinion because earlier it was working fine.

Here is my Coredns `Corefile`:

```
# cat Corefile
(global) {
    errors
    cache 86400 {
      prefetch 5 10m 10%
    }
    dnssec
    loadbalance
    prometheus :9153
  }


.:53 {
    import global
    hosts  {
            192.168.1.16 my-self-hosted.ddns.com
            fallthrough
           }
    forward . 1.1.1.1:53 {
    tls_servername cloudflare-dns.com
    health_check 10s
   }
    loop
    reload       
}

tls://.:853 {
  tls /etc/coredns/cert.pem /etc/coredns/key.pem
  forward . 1.1.1.1:53
}
```

from my local node, I expect nslookup my-self-hosted.ddns.com to resolve to 192.168.1.16 ip as defined in the my coredns's corefile.

I have changed name and address to hide original here.

Comment: "Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.15" This means this server is not configured correctly as a recursive one, which is different from an authoritative one. But otherwise your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.